# Units in the group ring over fours group after Gardam

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-rings, group-algebras

Giles Gardam recently found ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11818)) that Kaplansky's unit conjecture fails on a virtually abelian torsion-free group, over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$.

This conjecture asserted that if $\Gamma$ is a torsion-free group and $K$ is a field, then every invertible element in the group ring $K\Gamma$ is a nonzero scalar multiple of a group element.

Consider the fours group
$$ P = \langle a, b, A, B \;|\; a = A^{-1}, b = B^{-1}, (a^2)^b = a^{-2}, (b^2)^a = b^{-2} \rangle $$
(Gardam calls it the Promislow group). This group is a join of two Klein bottle groups and fits in a non-split exact sequence $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^3 \rightarrow P \rightarrow C_2^2 \rightarrow 1$. Now in the group ring $\mathbb{F}_2[G]$ we have $pq = 1$ where
$$ p = 1 + aa + aaa + aab + AABA + aaBA + aaBABA + aabABA + aabb + ab + aba + abaBa + ababa + aBAbb + Abb + b + bA + BABA + bABA + BAbb + bb $$
and
$$ q = 1 + a + AA + aaab + aaababb + AAAbb + aaB + AABB + Ab + aB + AbaB + Abab + abaB + abab + AbaBa + Ababa + abaBB + abbb + B + BA + BB, $$
so Kaplansky's unit conjecture is false.

So an obvious question is:

> What can we now say about the group of units in $\mathbb{F}_2[G]$?

I claim no originality in observing that this question can be asked (I saw Avinoam Mann discuss this question on Twitter). I gave this five minutes of thought myself and I see that the group is residually finite and contains a copy of $P$ (:P). Two random questions that are particularly interesting to me (but any information is welcome).

> Is this group finitely-generated? Is it amenable?

Such questions do not seem obviously impossible on a quick look (for the first, some kind of Gaussian elimination? for the latter, use the fact the group has very slow growth somehow?), but they don't seem obvious either. I assume there is no information in the literature explicitly about the units in group rings of torsion-free groups, because we didn't know they can be nontrivial. But people have studied group rings a lot and I don't have much background on them, so maybe more is known than I was able to see. One fun thing to look at is the following:

> What is the isomorphism type of the subgroup $\langle p, P \rangle$ of the group of units?

I checked that p has order at least $10$, and I suppose it must have infinite order. I checked also that the $3$-sphere generated by $p$ and $a$ has no identities, but $p$ and $b$ satisfy some identities.

Comment: it might be nice to mention what are $A$ and $B$ (although I'll admit it's a fairly common shortcut)

Comment: I realized that some time after posting but I figured it's not worth bumping the post over. Inverses included in presentation now.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a point in your last question, but the zero divisor conjecture (which holds for the group $P$ since it is solvable) implies the idempotent conjecture. If $p$ had finite order, that would contradict the zero divisor conjecture, since $0 = p^n-1 = (p-1)(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2} + \ldots + p^2 + p + 1)$. (Also the convention that a capital letter is an inverse is very misleading there, since $p$ is an element and $P$ is either the inverse of $p$ or the group $P$; but again it's just me being pointy)

Comment: Ok I did not connect the dots there. So on $P$, we can immediately say that the group of units of the group ring is torsion-free.

Comment: You are also correct about the capital notation being confusing, it's just that I imagined some people will find it useful for the formula to be copy-pasteable for quick checking, and I figured the $A$ & $B$ convention is better for that than $^{-1}$. I copied and pasted it from my little Python script.

Comment: As for amenability, the monoid $\mathbb{F}_2[P]$ is surely amenable. Look at $F_i =$ elements supported on the ball of radius $i$, then for any element $p \in \mathbb{F}_2[P]$, $\lim_i \tfrac{|pF_i| }{|F_i|} =1$. Is there a result to conclude that a subgroup of an amenable monoid is amenable? A submonoid of a amenable group is not always amenable. (and yes, the capital letters are very convenient to copy in code!)

Comment: here would be an argument for "of $G$ is a subgroup of an amenable monoid $M$, then $G$ is amenable": the subgroup $G$ partitions $M$ in right cosets (this uses that $G$ is a group); take a bunch $m_i$ of representatives for the $G$-cosets; given a function $f$ in $\ell^{\infty}G$ extend it to $\ell^{\infty}M$ by $\tilde{f}(m_ig) = f(g)$; define the invariant mean on $\ell^{\infty}G$ by $\mu(f) = \mu_M(\tilde{f})$ where $\mu_M$ is an invariant mean on the monoid $M$.

Comment: If it works it's a good answer. But do check the formulas, at least one looks iffy to me (maybe a typo in the limit).

Comment: I mean I believe $|pF_i|/|F_i|=1$ so the limit is 1 too, but that's not amenability. As for the correct formula, I don't see why it holds.

Comment: yes, I wrote garbage. I'll try to write things properly (if it works) sometime in the not too far future.

Comment: The group $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_2[P])$ is not amenable, so be careful.

Comment: @ARG this is a very theoretical question at this point, but can you get a contradiction to the zero divisor conjecture from a torsion element if the field isn't $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: @GilesGardam: Isn't $0 = p^n -1 = (p-1)(p^{n-1} + \cdots + p + 1)$ a perfectly fine proof? Oh wait, why isn't the latter term $0$? I suppose I didn't understand the proof.

Comment: @GilesGardam (& VilleSalo) It was probably careless speculation from my part to extend the idempotent conjecture to all $n$. So the "correct" statement of the idempotent conjecture is with $n=2$, and in this case $(p-1)(p+1)$ is clearly a zero divisor (even over $\mathbb{F}_2$) [note that the variation of idempotent with $p^n=p$ works for $n=2$ or $3$]. But indeed, a torsion element of odd order $>2$ might not be an actual contradiction... One can always hope that for an explicit element $p^{n-1} + \cdots + p + 1$ can be shown to be non-zero, but that might be a tall order.

Comment: @GilesGardam & VilleSalo a silly remark: when $n$ is prime, then over $\mathbb{F}_n$ there cannot be $n$ torsion, since $0=p^n -1  = (p-1)^n$ (so one of the powers of $(p-1)^k$ times $(p-1)$ form a zero divisor. This makes it unlikely (but not impossible) to have torsion over $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: This torsion question reminds me of my other question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339692/can-matrices-over-fg-have-infinite-order-when-g-is-periodic (which is still completely open). These are such mysterious things.

Comment: @VilleSalo This is why math is so fun: you have mysterious things that can be so elegantly solved (I'm referring to Giles' Answer)

Comment: @GilesGardam  Do you think that 21 is the least length for a possible counterexample? Have you done any work on elements of length 19?

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi 21 is the smallest that I know of. Maybe 21 is minimal for this group but not for all groups?

Comment: Have you thought about any question in the direction "showing that the group of units is not too small"? For instance, is it immediate that $P$ has infinite index? Can a lower bound on the (possibly infinite Hirsch length) be given? can it be shown that the group of units is not virtually abelian? etc. The amenability question sounds a bit elaborate to start with, since amenability is not purely algebraic (well it is, but for quite elaborate very recent reasons).

Comment: @YCor: This was somehow what my last paragraph was meant to be about. I checked more carefully and I retract my claim about a small identity satisfied by $p$ and $b$ (I don't know where I got that). I calculated some small balls and the pair $p,a$ seems to generate a free $7$-ball, i.e. all 4373 products are different. I wouldn't say this is very convincing of anything yet, but at least it's not immediately obvious even that this subgroup is not free.

Comment: What about powers? could one describe powers of $a$ and show that no power of $a$ is a group element? computing some small powers might be doable.

Comment: I'm not following, is $a$ the generator or is it Giles' polynomial $p$? I'll check powers of $p$ after the $8$-ball finishes. (Ok it finished right this second, seems the $8$-ball is free. Do recheck, I wrote very messy Python code without careful checking because I wasn't planning to do original research.)

Comment: Support sizes according to my script 1:21, 2:129, 3:469, 4:1005, 5:2029, 6:3421, 7:5673, 8:8111, 9:11469, 10:15961, 11:21767, 12:27905, 13:35759, 14:44707, 15:55863, 16:65999, 17:75527, 18:90003, 19:110467, 20:128909. I could go further but I feel that's disrespectful to my computer, I really doubt that suddenly collapses to one.

Comment: Still the successive quotients decrease which doesn't clearly show an exponential growth.

Comment: By the way $P$ embeds into a split abelian-by-finite group and such questions might be natural to ask in this setting (allowing torsion), in which case the first test case would be describing units in $\mathbf{F}_2D_\infty$.

Comment: Well, we don't have exponential growth, it's bounded by the growth of the group? (The list of pairs $n:k$ was the answer to what I guessed you were asking, so the size $k$ of the support of the polynomial $p^n$ where $p$ is the polynomial of Giles.)

Comment: Oh, of course :) one should rather check if $\log(u_n)/\log(n)$ seems to converge to a positive limit.

Comment: One could of course ask whether we reach the (cubic) growth of this group. I can check the densities.

Comment: You can check what you suggest (the "dimension" of the support), but the dimension could be full (so the limit is three) and you could even have positive density. That's what I would guess happens; except for the boundaries you fill about half the ball.

Comment: In the post I represent $p$ over the generators $a$, $b$, and the radius is $7$. So I used that to calculate. The support of $p$ is size $21$ and the $7$-ball in $P$ has cardinality $363$. The density is thus 5.8 percent. Taking powers and considering the density in the $7n$-ball, we get approximately 1:0.058, 2:0.050, 3:0.056, 4:0.052, 5:0.054, 6:0.053, 7:0.056, i.e. the density doesn't seem to change. (This doesn't seem very surprising to me, it's a complicated cellular automaton, but again I do recommend someone checks these numbers.)

Comment: Maybe the correct thing to do is to compare with the growth of the submonoid generated by the support of $p$. By amenability, assuming this monoid is a group (I didn't check this though) I would expect that the boundary behavior eventually disappears and the density goes to about a half. Calculated like this I get relative densities 1:1.000, 2:0.648, 3:0.588, 4:0.500, 5:0.499, 6:0.475, 7:0.489, 8:0.462, 9:0.455, 10:0.458, 11:0.466, 12:0.458 for $p^n$.

Comment: This group is naturally a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_4(R)$, $R=\mathbf{F}_2[a^{\pm 1}, b^{\pm 1}, c^{\pm 1}])=\mathbf{F}_2[\mathbf{Z}^3]$ and in particular satisfies the Tits alternative: has a free subgroup, or virtually solvable of small length. See my comment to https://mathoverflow.net/a/387186/14094

Comment: @Ycor my memory is murky... what's the bound on the length (if solvable)? one could eventually check commutators of the unit $p$, its powers $p^n$ and their conjugates...

Comment: Ooh that's a great idea

Comment: We need a bound on the index of the solvable subgroup too, but assuming we have those I think this gives that both amenability and nonamenability can be decided from a finite ball. I guess that was @YCor's idea. I don't know where the strongest bounds are given but I can fire up my script...

Comment: At this point I think one should first compute explicitly this embedding into $4\times 4$ matrices, and make explicit these matrices corresponding to the units $p,q$ (and also to the trivial units $a,b$). The knowledge of these matrices, their characteristic polynomial etc should provide useful information on the Zariski closure of the group they generate, say much information about their powers, etc.

Comment: Of course, but are there abstract bounds known for the index so that we can immediately find some explicit $n$ such that this group is nonamenable iff it contains a free $n$-ball?

Comment: I mean, it would be cool to know an absolute upper bound on the amount of computation that needs to be done.

Comment: FWIW, I computed 5000 elements of the Gardam group (I mean the one generated by $a,b,p$), always multiplying previous ones by $a,b,p$ and always keeping only the 5000 with minimal ($> 1$) length and secondarily minimal total length (with some arbitrary convention), until this converged. I found $5000$ elements of support $21$, nothing with less. (This is about the exchange between Abdollahi and Gardam, maybe Gardam went further already?)

Comment: @Ycor & VilleSalo yes that was exactly what I was fishing for: a computable criterion to decide for solvability (perhaps it can only conclude non-solvability). Given that it seems feasible to compute relatively large elements in the group (at least VilleSalo can do it, my computing skills are too thin for this), one should be able to get something. But it would be nice to know where to stop! And it's true too, the matrices are probably computable. Looks like this might open some original research!

Comment: Yes I guess I thought without thinking that it's enough to check commutators of generators up to some depth by commutator formulas, but I don't think that's true. The matrices should be easy to produce, I can do it (but no easier than anyone else).

Comment: (I didn't mean to promise I'll do it, anyone feel free to produce them.)

Comment: @VilleSalo Yes I think computing commutators will only give you that the group is not solvable (but then it's important to have the bound on the solvable length)

Comment: ...and on the index

Comment: @Ycor & VilleSalo I don't know if there are guidelines as to when one should stop sharing "research ideas" on MO (or perhaps you guys should start a paper). But I sure would like to see those matrices.

Comment: @VilleSalo correct, and on the index...

Answer (score 18):

Good questions! To bump the discussion of torsion out of the comments: the group of units of $\mathbb{F}_2[P]$ is torsion-free. Suppose we have $q$-torsion and factor $0 = x^q - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{q-1} + \dots + x + 1)$. For $q = 2$ this immediately contradicts the zero divisor conjecture unless $x = 1$. For odd $q$ we use the fact that $x$ must map to $1 \in \mathbb{F}_2$ under the augmentation map to see that $1 + x + \dots + x^{q-1} \neq 0$ and get the contradiction.

Any non-trivial unit in $\mathbb{Z} G$ for $G$ torsion-free (if such a thing exists!) is infinite order by a theorem of Sehgal.

*Sehgal, Sudarshan K.*, [**Certain algebraic elements in group rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01229717), Arch. Math. 26, 139-143 (1975). [ZBL0322.20002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0322.20002).

Overdue update: my paper now has a corollary showing that the group of units has free subgroups and is not finitely generated. Furthermore, Murray has given non-trivial units in all positive characteristics (see [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02147)).

Comment: Very nice! Just to correct my previous comment: assume $x^n=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$. WLOG assume $n$ is the first integer to do so. Then if $p|n$, $0=x^n-1=(x^{n/p}-1)^p$ so $x^{n/p}-1$ and some power of $x^{n/p}-1$ form a zero divisor. If $n=2$ then $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1) =0$ contradicts zero divisor again. If $n$ is $>2$ and coprime to $p$, $0=x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)$. Now sending $y \in \mathbb{F}_p[G]$ to the sum of its coefficients $\epsilon(y)$ (augmentation map), one has that $\epsilon(x)^n=1$. Since $\epsilon(x)^p=\epsilon(x)$, then $\epsilon(x)^{n \text{ mod}(p-1)}=1$. So ...

Comment: are there $\epsilon \in \mathbb{F}_p$ with $\epsilon^n=1$, $2<n <p-1$ and $ \epsilon^{n-1} + \cdots + \epsilon + 1 =0$? It's not too hard to check that this is not the case for $p=3$ or 5. But then this fails with $p=7$: one has $n=4$ and $\epsilon(x) = -1$. However one can then exclude 4-torsion using $x^4-1 = (x^2-1)(x^2+1)$, since $\epsilon(x)^2 = -1$ has no solution with $p=7$. So is there a general argument for any $p$?

Comment: An element of a field that is a root of $x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1-0$ is an $n$th root of 1.  So for $n$ a prime that does not divide $p-1$ there won't be any such elements.

Comment: @IJL many thanks, but I found the "correct" argument (which is I believer much simpler); see next comment...

Comment: Assume $x^n=1$ in $K[G]$ for $K$ a field of characteristic $p$. WLOG assume $n$ is minimal. Then if $p|n$, $0=x^n-1=(x^{n/p}-1)^p$ so $x^{n/p}-1$ and some power of $x^{n/p}-1$ form a zero divisor [or contradicts minimality]. Otherwise one has $\epsilon(x)^n = 1$. So look at $x' = x/\epsilon(x)$ (we are in a field after all so $1/\epsilon(x)$ exists). Then $\epsilon(x')=1$ and $x'^n=1$.Then $0=x'^n-1=(x'-1)(x'^{n-1}+\cdots+x'+1)$. Since $\epsilon(x')=1$, one has that $\epsilon(x'^{n-1}+\cdots+x'+1)=n \neq 0$ as $(n,p)=1$. The factorisation of $x'^n -1$ contradicts zero divisor.

Comment: Actually, the argument works in any ring of characteristic $p$, since $\epsilon(x)^{n-1}$ will be a multiplicative inverse of $\epsilon(x)$. 

So good new Giles: any torsion element in any ring of positive characteristic will contradict zero divisors!

Comment: If I'm correct $(KP)^\times$ has no torsion beyond scalars (so torsion forms a central subgroup naturally isomorphic to $K^*$), for arbitrary field $K$; this is a bit long for a comment and I wrote the argument as an answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/387096/14094

Comment: just wanted to point out that as GAP was apparently used in the work, it ought to be in references. https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/cite.html

Answer (score 6):

This is an extended comment, follow-up to [Giles Gardam's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/386187/14094) and the comments therein. Recall that the group of nonzero scalars $K^\times$ is a central subgroup of $(KG)^\times$ (for each group $G$ and field $K$).

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be a group and $K$ a field, such that $\bar{K}G$ has no zero divisor. Then the group $(KG)^\times/K^\times$ is torsion-free. In particular, every torsion element in $(KG)^\times$ is a scalar.

Here $K\subset \bar{K}$ is an algebraic closure. For arbitrary fields, the assumption on $G$ is satisfied by torsion-free virtually solvable groups (and hence residually torsion-free solvable groups, such as free groups and many more).

**Lemma 1.**  Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra (=unital associative $K$-algebra) with no zero divisors. If $P\in K[t]\smallsetminus\{0\}$ and $P(x)=0$ for $x\in A$ then $x$ is a scalar.

Proof: just consider the unital $K$-subalgebra generated by $x$. It is commutative, finite-dimensional over $K$, and has no nonzero divisor, hence is a field, and hence is 1-dimensional since $K$ is algebraically closed.

In turn this implies:

**Lemma 2.** Let $G$ be a group and $K$ a field for which $\bar{K}G$ has no zero divisor. Then for every nonzero polynomial $P\in K[t]$, every element $x$ in $KG$ such that $P(x)=0$ for some nonzero polynomial $P$, is a scalar.

Proof: by Lemma 1, $x$ is a scalar in $\bar{K}G$, and hence is a scalar in $KG$.

Lemma 2 in turn, applied to $P(t)=t^n-\lambda$ for any fixed $\lambda\in K$, immediately implies the proposition.

---

Edit: the second sentence of the proposition can be restated as: if $K$ is a domain and $\overline{\mathrm{Frac}(K)}G$ has no zero divisors, then every torsion element in $(KG)^\times$ is a scalar. This is obtained in [ARG's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/386475/14094) just assuming that $KG$ itself has no zero divisors.

Comment: nice! I also wrote up a "clean" version of my comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385712/units-in-the-group-ring-over-fours-group-after-gardam/386475#386475); the arguments work for any commutative ring (but without the algebraic closure). Which raises two questions: 1- is it easier to get the zero divisor conjecture on the algebraic closure than on the base field? 2- did you mean "Since the degree is positive, $P$ has a root $s$ in $\overline{K}$"?

Comment: @ARG For 2: I need algebraically closed in Lemma 1, it disappeared by some cut-paste accident (it's clearly false otherwise, just considering a nontrivial finite extension). I corrected

Comment: @ARG As regards your question 1: of course the zero divisor conjecture is stronger when the algebra is larger. So I'm just assuming something a bit stronger than it for $KG$. In the known instances, the proof might be the same for all fields. Also, for given $G$, the zero divisor (resp. idempotent) conjecture for every field is equivalent to the zero divisor (resp. idempotent) conjecture for every **finite** field, by a simple classical approximation argument.

Comment: For those who are interested in the details of "finite fields $\implies$ all fields" see this [other post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62548/zero-divisor-conjecture-for-finite-fields?rq=1)

Comment: @ARG here are the details in a more concise way. Suppose the result known for all finite fields. Let $K$ be a domain and suppose that $KG$ fails one of the conjectures (has a idempotent, zero divisor, unit, nilpotent...). Passing to a finitely generated subdomain we can suppose $K$ finitely generated. Since every f.g. domain is residually a finite field, taking a suitable quotient we get a finite field $F$ with a counterexample of the same conjecture for $FG$.

Comment: thanks for this concise presentation. Still it's sometimes interesting to get the full meanders that can lead someone to a given conclusion.

Comment: @ARG actually the even more concise way (and intuitive, to me) is that the set of rings for which such a conjecture holds is stable under taking subrings, directed limits, and ultraproducts. This is enough to pass from finite fields to arbitrary domains. [By the way this is also known at the level of the group (passes to subgroups, directed limits, and ultraproducts)]. Of course this reflects here the principle that every system of polynomial equations and inequalities that has a solution in a domain has a solution in a finite field and this can be written in detail, quantitatively etc.

Comment: That's a very nice insight indeed! And of course now we know this does not work for [non-split] extensions (since the group $P$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}^3$). [But there is no reason to believe it would have held for extensions.]

Comment: @ARG but the unit conjecture is not true for finite groups, so this doesn't say much about stability by extensions.

Comment: ah yes... I overlooked that. So "stability by extension" remains unclear. Interesting!

Answer (score 4):

Let me describe how I would try amenability. I'll make it in two steps (the first step is fine; the second is more of a work in progress) by going through the [possible] amenability of the monoid $R[G] \setminus \{0\}$. I discuss below why I think this strategy seems fine.

The first step is relatively straightforward.
Let me call a partially-absorbing element of a monoid $M$ an element $x$ such that for some $m \in M$ with $m \neq 1$, $xm = x$. Note that if the ring $R[\Gamma]$ has no zero divisors, there cannot be such an element except 0 (since $xm = x$ implies $x(m-1) =0$.

**Lemma 1:** let $M$ be an [right-]amenable monoid without partially-absorbing elements and $G$ be a subgroup of $M$. Then $G$ is amenable.

*Proof:* Let $\mu$ be a right-invariant mean on $\ell^\infty(M)$, that is $\forall m \in M, \forall f \in \ell^\infty(M)$ one has $\mu(\rho_mf) = \mu(f)$ (here $\rho_mf(x) := f(xm)$). Now consider the right-$G$-cosets of $M$, and choose representatives $m_i$ so that $\{m_iG\}$ covers $M$. (Note that being in the same $G$-coset is an equivalence relation because $G$ is a group; also note that the cosets are "naturally" identified with $G$ since there are no partially-absorbing elements).

Define a mean $\mu_G$ on $G$ as follows. For $f\in \ell^\infty(G)$ consider $f_M \in \ell^\infty(M)$ by $f_M(m) = f(g)$ where $m \in Gm_i$ so that $m = m_ig$. (Basically $f_M$ is a copy of $f$ on each $G$-coset.)
Define $\mu_G(f) = \mu(f_M)$.
Note that $\rho_gf_M(x) = f_M(xg)$.
Then $\mu_G(\rho_gf) = \mu(\rho_gf_M) = \mu(f_M) = \mu_G(f)$.
From there $G$ has an invariant mean and is consequently amenable (on the right, but then also on the left)$\qquad \square$

**Remark:** It follows from Lemma 1 that if $R[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$ is amenable [and satisfies the zero divisor conjecture] then $\Gamma$ is amenable (because $\Gamma$ is embedded in $R[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$ by sending $\gamma$ to the element solely supported on $\gamma$ and with coefficient 1.

Now the next "step" (the amenability of $R[G] \setminus \{0\}$) should be well-known (or known to be open? or perhaps well-known to be false? ).
I posted it as a [separate question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386507/is-the-group-ring-of-an-amenable-group-viewed-as-multiplicative-monoid-amenabl).

Before moving on, let me just point out why this strategy does not seem so bad.
Start with $\Sigma_0 =\Gamma$ (embedded as Dirac masses), then consider the monoid $\Sigma_1$ which is generated by elemetns of the form $1+\gamma$, then consider the monoid $\Sigma_2$ which is generated by elements with support of size $\leq 3$, etc.
This gives a step by step process which seems easier to tackle (either in postive [amenable] or negative [non-amenable]).
One might think that this brings too many elements, but the conjugate of the unit element $p$ under $\Gamma$ has an infinite orbit.
So it seems likely that any positive [or negative] argument for the monoid will transfer to the group of units.
The obvious argument against this strategy, is that there are many more tools to conclude of the amenability of groups, than of monoids.

**Problem 2:** Assume $\Gamma$ is a countable amenable group, $R$ is a finite field and that the group ring over $R[\Gamma]$ satisfies the zero divisor conjecture. Show that the multiplicative monoid $M = R[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$ is a [right-]amenable monoid.

Applying a positive answer to Problem 2 would show that $R[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$ is an amenable monoid, and then applying Lemma 1 to the group of units of $R[\Gamma]$ shows it is an amenable group.

[**EDIT:** as updated in Gilles' answer above, the group of unit is not amenable. So the interesting problem would either be: 1- is there any non-abelian group for which the multiplicative monoid (without 0) is amenable? 2- which $\Sigma_i$ is the first to be non-amenable?]

*In support of* the amenability of $\Sigma_1$ (the monoid generated by the Dirac masses and the elements of the from $1+\gamma$).
Each element of $\Sigma_1$ can be written in the form $\gamma \prod_{\eta \in S} (1+ \eta)$ where $S \in (\Gamma)^N$ (is an ordered $N$-tuple).
The element $\prod_{\eta \in S} (1+ \eta)$ is closely related to $\prod_{\eta \in S} \eta$.
Indeed it will be (at most) supported on all the possible partial products of $\prod_{\eta \in S} \eta$.
So this second part of the semigroup is very close to $\Gamma$ itself.
The difference with $\Gamma$ can be "measured" by how the different ways of writing an element $h$ as a product so that the partial products are distinct.
In some sense, this makes it sound that groups which are far from being Abelian should have a non-amenable $\Sigma_1$.
The question is then whether virtually-Abelian groups are far enough from being Abelian.

*Note:* Bartholdi has a paper about amenable $K$-algebras, but the notion of amenability he uses does not match with the amenability of the multiplicative monoid $K[G] \setminus \{0\}$. He uses the sequences $F_i$ (which clearly don't work here) in his paper.

Comment: I don't understand Lemma 2. For instance if $F_{i,k}$ happens to be just the set of all elements with support contained in $B_i$ (is that possible?) then it seems the "boundary effect" is quite big: almost all elements will have something on the support (even if only a small proportion of the "entropy" is generated there).

Comment: Indeed the estimates are quite hard to go through ... (and I do not claim to have done them). I'd be really surprised if $F_{i,k}$ would coincide with $F_i$ (especially since $i >> k$). But if the boundary effect is what bothers you here is another variant. Take $F_{i,j,k}$ to be the all the translates (in the sense of the usual action/embedding of $\Gamma$ in $R[\Gamma]$) of the elements of $F_{j,k}$ so that the support still lies in $B_i$. If $i >> j$ and $j$ is much larger than the support of any of the first $k$ elements in your enumeration, it "should" be fine.

Comment: @VilleSalo Come to think of it, there might be another variant which is easier to compute. Let $\Pi_{k,n}$ to be the elements which can be written as products of the $k$ first in your enumeration, with at most $n$ uses of each of these elements. Then let $\Phi_{i,k,n}$ to be the translates of these elements so that the support lies in $B_i$. Then $|\Phi_{i,k,n} \cap \Phi_{i,k,n} m| \geq |$all those products with at most $n-1$ appearances of $m|$ and the boundary effect is also negligible.

Comment: Quite possibly I just have a point in every open set, but I'm not really seeing these. One overarching problem is that everything you say seems to work just as well for the monoid of $2$-by-$2$-matrices over this group ring, and I know that one is not amenable.

Comment: @VilleSalo So there is clearly one thing which does not go through for the monoid of $2\times2$ matrices. Namely look at $\big( \begin{smallmatrix} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} \end{smallmatrix} \big)$ then, even if the support of these elements is contained in $B_i$, by multiplying with a simple matrix like $m=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \big) $ one gets that the resulting elements have support in $(B_i)^2$ and not $B_i S$ for a set $S$ which only depends on the element $m$. So I'm absolutely sure my arguments fails dramatically for this monoid.

Comment: @VilleSalo I decided to post it as [a separate question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386507/is-the-group-ring-of-an-amenable-group-amenable) because the status of this "lemma 2" should really have been settled a long time ago (in the 70's if not even before).

Comment: @VilleSalo sorry I completely misunderstood what you meant with the $2\times 2$ monoid. Now I see your point (at least for the sets $F_{i,k}$). For the sets $F_{i,k,n}$ I'm not sure yet (since $F_{i,k,n}$ is not closed under addition). I'll need to edit the answer at some point anyway (since there are hypothesis missing in Lemma 1!).

Answer (score 4):

Non-trivial torsion in the group of units of $K[G]$  contradicts the zero-divisor conjecture for $K[G]$. Here non-trivial means "which does not come from $K$ itself".

This answer rather answers a question of Giles in the comments and is essentially an expansion of the comment to Giles' answer; the aim is to show that if a commutative ring $K$ (of any characteristic!) is so that $K[G]$ satisfies the zero divisor conjecture, then there is no element $x \in K[G]$ such that $x^n = 1$ for $n>1$, unless $x \in K e_G$ (an element supported solely at the identity element of $G$; i.e. the ring $K$ itself has an element of $n$-torsion).

So assume $x^n=1$ and $x \notin K e_G$, and take $n$ to be the smallest integer to do so. There are two cases:

*Case 1:* if $K$ is of characteristic $p \neq 0$ and $p$ divides $n$, $0=x^n-1=(x^{n/p}-1)^p$ (Frobenius map; i.e. the binomial coefficients of a prime $p$ are all divisible by $p$).
It cannot happen that $x^{n/p}-1  =0$ (since it would contradict the minimality of $n$).
This means that $x^{n/p}-1$ and some power of $x^{n/p}-1$ form a zero divisor.

*Case 2:* if $p$ does not divide $n$ or $K$ is of characteristic 0, consider the augmentation map $\epsilon:K[G] \to K$... if $x = \sum_{g \in G} x_g g$ then $\epsilon(x) = \sum_{g \in G} x_g$.
Since $\epsilon$ is a ring homomorphism, $\epsilon(x)^n = 1$ (so $\epsilon(x)^{n-1}$ is a multiplicative inverse of $\epsilon(x)$).
Consider the element $x' = x \epsilon(x)^{n-1}$
Note that $x' \neq 1$, since that would mean that $x \in K e_G$.
Then $\epsilon(x') = \epsilon(x) \epsilon(x)^{n-1}=1$ and $x'^n= x^n \epsilon(x)^{n(n-1)}=1$ (this uses commutativity of the ring $K$).
Then $0=x'^n-1=(x'-1)(x'^{n-1}+\cdots+x'+1)$.
Since $\epsilon(x')=1$, one has that $\epsilon(x'^{n-1}+\cdots+x'+1) = \epsilon(x')^{n-1} + \cdots + \epsilon(x') + 1 =n \neq 0$ as either $n$ is not divisible by $p$ or $K$ has characteristic 0.
In particular $x'^{n-1}+\cdots+x'+1 \neq 0$ and $x'-1 \neq 0$.
But $(x'-1)(x'^{n-1}+\cdots+x'+1) =0$ form a zero divisor.

*Remark 1:* Note that if $K[G]$ has no zero divisors, then any element $x$ such that $x^n = x^k$ for $n \neq k$, is a torsion element. Indeed, $0 = x^n-x^k = x^k (x^{n-k} -1)$. Since $x^k \neq 0$, this means that $x^{n-k}=1$.

*Remark 2:* I guess this is all well-known, but for some reason I could only find references to the case $n=2$ (which is much easier since $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ and $x \pm 1$ is never 0 [unless $x = \pm e_G$]).

Comment: This looks correct. So it seems your original argument only needed a little bit of augmentation to deal with all commutative rings.

Comment: @VilleSalo a bit of augmentation and a bit of Frobenius :D

Comment: @VilleSalo it's not really "all commutative rings" but rather "all domains". Indeed the zero divisor conjecture for fields implies it for domains, and conversely $RG$ has zero divisors when $R$ is not a domain.

Comment: So we agree that ARG shows that "no zero divisors in $RG$ implies no torsion in $RG$" holds in all commutative rings (as I assume I meant with my comment), and you're saying it's silly to include non-domains, since the implication is trivial for them?

Comment: Actually the main point of my comment was probably to make the augmentation pun.

Comment: @VilleSalo just when you think you have a nice argument, there comes a pundit to rob you of it (no offense to Ycor meant and no content added, just a silly [and perhaps overused] pun).

Comment: @Ycor still I have the feeling that one could improve my statement by saying that if the only zero-divisors are those of $K$ then the only idempotents are those of $K$ (but I had enough fun with the current argument). One question which still tickles me is whether one can do something with skew fields.

Comment: @ARG I have no idea what you mean by *"the only zero-divisors are those of $K$"*... if there are zero divisors in $K$, say $ab=0$, $a,b\neq 0$ and $G\neq\{1\}$, then there are plenty of zero divisors outside $K$ (such as $a\delta_g$ or $a(\delta_1-\delta_g)$ for $g\neq 1$.

Comment: @Ycor I did not have any specific in mind (this is why I used the word "feeling"). If I have the time, maybe I'll think it through, but I have (unfortunately, because this is fun) more pressing things to attend. So just ignore this last comment.