# Is the group ring of an amenable group, viewed as multiplicative monoid, amenable?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, amenability, group-rings

Motivated by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385712/units-in-the-group-ring-over-fours-group-after-gardam) question, it seems natural to ask the following:

**Question 1:** Is there a [finitely generated discrete] torsion-free virtually Abelian (but not Abelian) group $G$ so that the multiplicative monoid $R \setminus \{0\}$ of  $R = \mathbb{F}_2[G]$ its [group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is [right-]amenable?

Note that for virtually Abelian groups the zero-divisor conjecture holds, so it makes sense to speak of the multiplicative monoid of $R$.
Amenable here means the existence of an invariant mean i.e. an element $\mu$ in the dual of $\ell^\infty(M)$ so that $\mu$ is invariant under the translation action of the monoid; I don't actually care if it's right or left amenable, but it only needs to be one of both.
If the group is Abelian, then the monoid is also Abelian hence amenable.

**Question 2:** Is there a [finitely generated discrete] torsion-free non-Abelian amenable group $G$ so that: (1) the zero-divisor conjecture holds for $R = K[G]$ (the group ring over some finite field $K$) and (2) the multiplicative monoid of $R \setminus \{0\}$ is [right-]amenable?

Lastly one could also replace the base ring $K$ by $\mathbb{Z}$. I stumbled on this question while trying to give a *tentative* [positive] answer over [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385712/units-in-the-group-ring-over-fours-group-after-gardam/386261#386261), but this tentative answer is false and it seems the questions above should have been settled long ago. Or maybe the answer to this question (for some group) has an implication to an open problem? In any case, it would be nice to have the status of this (probably?) well-studied question.

This [thesis](https://eprints.utas.edu.au/18589/1/Whole-Deprez-thesis.pdf) gives a good overview of amenability for semigroups (and hence monoids). Note that if the group $G$ is Abelian, then the multiplicative monoid of $K[G]$ is also Abelian and hence amenable (result which goes back to Day or Markov/Kakutani).

PS: I'm hitting lots of pay-walls when going through references, so apologies for not being able to complete the history check.

First EDIT: removed the zero from the monoid (otherwise the measure supported at 0 is a mean); added torsion-free hypothesis to avoid zero-divisors in Question 1; added that the zero-divisors should hold in Question 2 for the same reason.

Second EDIT: in view of recent developments, I changed the formulation of the question to make them still pertinent.

Comment: There seems to also be a notion of amenability of algebras (which makes the title a bit confusing).

Comment: My vague memory is that any monoid with a multiplicative zero is amenable so the multiplicative monoid of a ring is always amenable

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg yes obviously... the measure is then concentrated at the 0-element. I forgot to mention that its the amenability of the multiplicative monoid of $K[G]$ without its 0 element... Should I edit the post?

Comment: @Ycor sure but the amenability of $K$-algebras (as in  Bartholdi) is something else than the amenability of the multiplicative monoid (without its 0-element).

Comment: What does it mean for a monoid to be amenable without its zero element?  I'ts not a monoid any more?

Comment: If your group ring has no zero divisors then this makes sense.  So you at least want the group torsion-free. Still I think only the Kaplansky idempotent conjecture is known for amenable torsion-free groups.

Comment: Just look at $M= K[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$ as a multiplicative semigroup. it still has an identity element (namely $1e_\Gamma$), but no absorbing element. Amenable then means that for any $m \in K[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$ and any function $f \in \ell^\infty(M)$ , $\mu( \rho_m f ) = \mu(f)$ where $\rho_f$ is the right regular representation, i.e. $\rho_mf (x) = f(xm)$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg true, I need no zero divisors, otherwise it is not a monoid. (But the zero divisor conjectures holds for virtually Abelian and elementarily amenable groups.) OK, I'll edit the post ... these are a lot of caveats...

Comment: But for that you need $K\Gamma\setminus \{0\}$ to be a semigroup.  The zero divisor conjecture is known to hold for elementary amenable groups, but I don't think it is known to hold for all amenable groups.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg correct, it is not known if we have zero divisors for any amenable groups, but still the second question is interesting for any group where this conjecture is known to hold.

Comment: I believe if $G$ is torsion-free virtually abelian, then the group ring of $G$ is an Ore domain and so has a division ring of fractions.  I think that in the literature you can find amenability is better understood for monoids with an Ore condition and so maybe Question 1 is easier.  Ore condition is sometimes known as right or left reversibility in the semigoup literature

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg many thanks for this information! would you happen to have a reference that for torsion-free virtually abelian $G$ the group ring is an Ore domain? I'll try to look it through, but I have problems with pay walls.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Ok it seems amenability of the group implies that the group ring is an Ore domain (a result of Tamari 1954). Very helpful. thanks!

Comment: That seems strange since I was under the impression that the zero divisor conjecture is only known for elementary amenable groups. Cor 4.6 http://intranet.math.vt.edu/people/plinnell/research/durham.pdf  does the virtually abelian case

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg You are perfectly right. I used a paper of [Guba](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.00344.pdf) to get the reference to Tamari. I suppose they are inverting only the non-zero divisors in the ring (since as you mention, the zero divisors conjecture is not known to hold for groups which are not elementarily amenable). So the Ore condition is only on non-zero divisor elements...

Comment: Apparently assuming the zero divisor conjecture holds for G the group ring is Ore iff the group is amenable