# A question on Giles Gardam counter example to the Unit conjecture of Kaplansky

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, open-problems

The unit version of the Kaplansky   conjecture is  about units in $FG$ where $F$ is  a field  and  $G$ is  a  torsion free  group. In a  recent counter example  by Giles Gardam,    it is  given  an  example of  a  non trivial unit when $F=F_2$ is the field with 2 elements  and  G is a finitely presented torsion free group. See this [MO post for some discussions on this counter example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385712/units-in-the-group-ring-over-fours-group-after-gardam).

The  group G in Giles Gardam counterexample is  a  result of  a group extension $Z^3\to G\to Z_2\times Z_2$. So it would be helpful to study some  other extensions of $Z^3$ by this quotient group? Do they generate other examples?

Comment: By Bieberbach's theorem, torsion-free extensions of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ are precisely the fundamental groups of closed, flat 3-manifolds. These are classified, and there are known to be 10 of them (see eg, §4 of Scott's notes: https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~pscott/8geoms.pdf). Gardam cites a paper of Craven--Pappas (https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1144) who explain that any possible counterexample should not be right-orderable. It is not hard to see that, for any closed 3-manifold $M$ with $H_1(M)$ infinite, $\pi_1M$ is locally indicable hence right-orderable. In conclusion... (tbc)

Comment: (cont'd) one should look for closed flat 3-manifold groups with finite $H_1(M)$. Wikipedia seems to suggest that Gardam's example ("the Hantzsche–Wendt manifold") is the only one -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hantzsche%E2%80%93Wendt_manifold --  ("It is the only closed flat 3-manifold with first Betti number zero.") but it would be nice to find a proper reference.

Comment: @HJRW  Than  you very  much  for  these very  informative  and helpful  comments

Comment: @HJRW  Thanks  again  for  sharing  the  beautiful  papers. They  will help me to learn a lot and  even better  understanding the  Giles  Gardam  ideas